# Search filename having unknown text within search text in Linux

Tags: linux

I am curious whether it is possible to do a Linux search with unknown text in between the search text.

String inside the file  `"redeem XXX reward [another string] reward [another string]"`

Expected string should inside the file name is `redeem XXX reward [another string]`

For instance  following search text `redeem XXX reward` XXX is a variable which I need to ignore while doing the search

```
$ grep -H "redeem XXX reward [another string]" /u01/temp/*.xml
```

Is there a way to include asterisk within the string.

Thanks

Comment: Do you specifically not want XXX? or do you want anything between redeem and reward?

Comment: @Leon Anything between redeem and reward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for occurrences of redeem followed by reward with any text in between you would use regex

```
grep -E "redeem.*reward" /u01/temp/*.xml
```

The dot means match any character and the asterisk matches 0 or more of the preceding character, anything in this case, until the next token is matched

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case I have more than one  `reward ` words in my string. I want to start the second part of search after * from immediate next `reward ` word. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @MPH I don't fully understand the changes you made to question, but it seems like you want `grep -E "redeem.*reward [another string]" /u01/temp/*.xml`

Comment: Thax. It's my bad I forgot to escape `blank ` in my command. Now all good.

Comment: is there way to create a regex for in search text above to include 2014-11-07T04:35:01Z instead of *

Comment: `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.` You can play around with regular expressions here http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Is there escaping characters here in unix. I ONLY escape `\ ` as follows `\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\ `. Looks like not accepting though

Comment: Sorry about that. In grep the character classes are different. \d is [[:digit:]] which I find way to verbose. you can rather write [0-9] so the pattern becomes `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.`

Comment: I tried this `grep -E "redeem[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}reward" /u01/temp/*.xml ` But looks like something wrong.

Comment: you are missing the dot to match the Z, you can also make that a literal Z, and I suspect you also want some sort of spacing between the date time and the string literals? `grep -E "redeem [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}. reward"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64700/discussion-between-mph-and-leon).

Comment: I included Z and spaces and . in my search then it gave me more files than expected
Since I know the exact number of characters in there. I tried `grep -E "redeem.{20}reward" /u01/temp/*.xml ` Still no luck.